# Find explicit formula for $y_{n}=\frac{1}{n (\sqrt 2)^n}+\frac{n-1}{n} y_{n-2}$

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

Is it possible to find a explicit formula here ?

This is the reduction formula of$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos x)^n dx$$.

If the limits are from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then the nice walli's formula can be obtained,however i have no idea regarding solving this kind of recurrences. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with
$$
y_n=\frac1{n\,2^{n/2}}+\frac{n-1}{n} y_{n-2}\tag1
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}=\frac{n}2\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)}$:
$$
\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+2}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}y_n
=\frac1{2^{\frac{n}2+1}}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}+\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)} y_{n-2}\tag2
$$
Thus, we get
$$
\overbrace{\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}y_{2n}}^{\large\alpha_n}
=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}+\overbrace{\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n-\frac12\right)}y_{2n-2}}^{\large\alpha_{n-1}}\tag3
$$
and
$$
\overbrace{\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+1\right)}y_{2n+1}}^{\large\beta_n}
=\frac1{2^{n+\frac32}}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+1\right)}+\overbrace{\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n\right)}y_{2n-1}}^{\large\beta_{n-1}}\tag4
$$
Therefore, noting that $\alpha_n=\alpha_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\alpha_k-\alpha_{k-1})$,
$$
y_{2n}=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+1\right)}\left[\frac{y_0}{\sqrt\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^{k+1}}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(k\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)}\right]\tag5
$$
and noting that $\beta_n=\beta_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\beta_k-\beta_{k-1})$,
$$
y_{2n+1}=\frac{\Gamma\!\left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac32\right)}\left[\frac{y_1\sqrt\pi}2+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^{k+\frac32}}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(k+1\right)}\right]\tag6
$$
It might be useful to recall that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ and $\Gamma\!\left(n+\tfrac12\right)=n!\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of closed forms for the sums in $(5)$ and $(6)$.

Comment: Wouldn't a sum with a finite number of terms qualify as a closed form?

Comment: @clathratus: if the sum has a fixed number of terms, yes. However, if the number of terms grows with $n$, I don't think it would.

Comment: @robjohn after (3) and (4)  how you obtained (5) and (6) , is it by the same method as clathratus has mentioned ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, if one can calculate something in a finite number of steps, that qualifies as a closed form $\Rightarrow$ +1

Comment: @MDesmond: I have added more connection between $(3)$ and $(5)$ and between $(4)$ and $(6)$. I hope that helps.

Comment: ■(1)using $$f_n=f_0\prod_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{n-k}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\beta_{n-j+1}$$ one can obtain 5,6 from 3,4 then why you have mentioned that $$\beta_n=\beta_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\beta_k-\beta_{k-1})$$ and $$\alpha_n=\alpha_0+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\alpha_k-\alpha_{k-1})$$ , in fact from your assumption $\alpha_{n}$ and $\beta_{n}$ are variable. How can you get that formula by not using the first mentioned fact and using two of your mentioned facts ? ■(2) How do you perfectly guess what gamma function to multiply?

Comment: @NewBornMATH: I was answering M Desmond's question about how I got $(5)$ and $(6)$ from $(3)$ and $(4)$. I did not use clathratus' formula, I simply used $\alpha_n=\frac{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}y_{2n}$ and $\alpha_k-\alpha_{k-1}=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(n\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}$ from $(3)$ to get $(5)$. Similarly, I used $\beta_n=\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}y_{2n+1}$ and $\beta_k-\beta_{k-1}=\frac1{2^{n+\frac32}}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}$ from $(4)$ to get $(6)$.

Comment: @NewBornMATH: if you have a recursion like $y_n=a_n+\frac{n-1}ny_{n-2}$, multiply by $b_n$ to get $b_ny_n=a_nb_n+b_n\frac{n-1}ny_{n-2}$. Now, we would like to find $b_n$ so that $b_{n-2}=b_n\frac{n-1}n$. Since the indices skip $2$, it is easier to substitute $n\mapsto2n$ to get $b_{2n}=b_{2n-2}\frac{n}{n-\frac12}$ which has a solution $b_{2n}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)}$, which says $b_n=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}$

Comment: @NewBornMATH: I am not sure what you mean by $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are variable. They are functions of $y_{2n}$ and $y_{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We can find an explicit formula for $y_n$ when $n$ is even. Here's how. Define 
$$D_n=y_{2n}$$
Hence we have 
$$D_n=\frac1{2n\cdot (\sqrt2)^{2n}}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}D_{n-1}$$
$$D_n=\frac1{2^{n+1}n}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}D_{n-1}$$
And we have the base case $D_0=\int_0^{\pi/4}dx=\pi/4$.

Then we note that, given the general recurrence $$f_n=\alpha_n+\beta_nf_{n-1}$$
Where $\alpha, \beta$ are explicit functions of $n$ and the base case $f_0$ is known. We have 
$$f_n=f_0\prod_{i=1}^{n}\beta_i+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{n-k}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\beta_{n-j+1}$$
Which is an explicit function of $n$. Choosing $\alpha_n=\frac1{2^{n+1}n}$ and $\beta_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n}$ We have 
$$D_n=\frac\pi4\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2i-1}{2i}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{k-n-1}}{n-k}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{2n-2j+1}{2n-2j+2}$$
$$D_n=\frac\pi{4^{n+1}}{2n\choose n}+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{2n-2j+1}{n-j+1}$$
I do not know how to simplify the final product anymore though. Note that this formula for $D_n$ works for integer $n\geq0$ because $\sum_{k=0}^{-1}:=0$ and $\prod_{j=1}^{0}:=1$

I hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

But why not use the following relationship

$$\cos^nx=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cos(n-2k)x$$

Then

$$y_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^nx \ dx=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\sin\frac{(n-2k)\pi}{4}}{n-2k}$$

The last formula works for $n=2m+1$

For $n=2m$ we get

$$y_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^nx \ dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{\sin\frac{(n-2k)\pi}{4}}{n-2k}$$

Comment: Can you please tell me where i can find the proof of that identity?

Comment: @MDesmond $\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, then raise to the n-th power and use Newton's Binomial Theorem. Finally,separate real and imaginary parts.